# Why mysqlbinlog utility displays two values instead of one?

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog, binlog

I am trying investigate something in binlog by `mysqlbinlog` utility. When I add verbose parameter `-vv` I see `INSERT` query with this part
`@2=-27170 (38366) /* SHORTINT meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */`

Does any one know why are there two numbers? What number was really part of `INSERT` sent to MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In binlog stream is no information about  integer signedness. So thats why I am seeing two numbers. It is described in this article https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/sign-row-based-binary-logging-and-integer-signedness-mysql-and-mariadb